# YUI3 autocomplete has images on top - How to get autocomplete to the top

Tags: yui

My auto YUI autocomplete zindex is off. How can I force the autocomplete DIV to the top.

[image]

Below I am using a standard template for YUI:

YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function(){
    YUI().use("autocomplete", "autocomplete-filters", "autocomplete-highlighters", function (Y) {
            var inputNode = Y.one('#name'),
                    tags = [
                        'css',
                        'css3',
                        'douglas crockford',
                        'ecmascript',
                        'html',
                        'html5',
                        'java',
                        'javascript',
                        'json',
                        'node.js',
                        'pie',
                        'yui'
                    ],
                    lastValue = '';

```
        inputNode.plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
                activateFirstItem: true,
                minQueryLength: 0,
                queryDelay: 0,
                source: tags,
                resultHighlighter: 'startsWith',
                resultFilters: ['startsWith']
        });

        // When the input node receives focus, send an empty query to display the full
        // list of tag suggestions.
        inputNode.on('focus', function () {
                inputNode.ac.sendRequest('');
        });

        // When there are new AutoComplete results, check the length of the result
        // list. A length of zero means the value isn't in the list, so reset it to
        // the last known good value.
        inputNode.ac.on('results', function (e) {
                if (e.results.length) {
                        lastValue = inputNode.ac.get('value');
                } else {
                        inputNode.set('value', lastValue);
                }
        });

        // Update the last known good value after a selection is made.
        inputNode.ac.after('select', function (e) {
                lastValue = e.result.text;
        });
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply to put the z-index in the css. Setting via JS used to be allowed, but as of YUI 3.4.0 it's a css-only flag (https://github.com/yui/yui3/blob/master/src/autocomplete/HISTORY.md).

The relevant CSS is (adjust your z-index as necessary):

```
.yui3-aclist { z-index: 100; }
```

PS., your YAHOO. line is from YUI2, so that is quite peculiar and definitely not a standard template.

By the time your callback in the YUI().use(...) section is called, the dom should be ready. No ondomready required.

Comment: jshirley, I am trying to provide a forced list. I am not up to speed on YUI, so your eye is sharp. If you know a way that I can do it in YUI 3 let me know. I am trying to force the list to popup when the field has focus.

Comment: It probably would have been better to edit this question, than asking about setting the CSS via JS in a separate question.

Comment: The above doesnt work. For some reason the yui-aclist is overridden with yui3-widget.\n<div id="yui_3_3_0_5_134653306431717" class="yui3-widget yui3-aclist yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-stacked yui3-aclist-hidden" style="width: 146px; left: 151.8148193359375px; top: 940.5741271972656px; z-index: 0; " aria-hidden="true">

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. I will check out the code. SEE MY COMMENT BELOW.  For some reason, yui-widget is overiding the yui3-aclist

Comment: JSHIRLEY YOU ROCK DUDE --- THANKS FOR THE POST, THATS WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR WITH ZINDEX FIXED